# Using if and elif the right way

Tags: pandas, if-statement

I have the following dataframe:

```
df1=pd.DataFrame([1,2,3], columns=["a"])
```

which results in:

```
    a
0   1
1   2
2   3
```

I want to create column b where each value is a multiple (x2,x3,x4) of the respective number in column a.
Desired output is like that:

```
    a   b
0   1   2
1   2   6
2   3   12
```

I try the following statement but obviously the behavior is not as expected.

```
for num in df1["a"]:
    if a == 1:
        df1["b"]=df1["a"]*2
    elif a == 2:
        df1["b"]=df1["a"]*3
    elif a ==3:
        df1["b"]=df1["a"]*4
```

when I run the above I get:

```
    a   b
0   1   2
1   2   4
2   3   6
```

help much appreciated

Comment: You dont need a loop: `df['b'] = df1['a'].add(1) * df1['a']`

Comment: Or without a pattern for cases with all **equality** checks I'd recommend using `map`: `df['a']*df['a'].map({1:2, 2:3, 3:4})`. The `else` clause can be handled by `.fillna(else_value)`

Comment: Assuming the sensible comments above don't solve your problem, the idiomatic if-elif-else pattern in pandas is using `np.select` or nested `np.where`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you use vectorized options : [`numpy select`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.select.html) covers your use case pretty well :

```
cond1 = df['a']==1
cond2 = df['a']==2
cond3 = df['a']==3
condlist=[cond1,cond2,cond3]
choicelist=[df.a*2,df.a*3, df.a*4]
df['b']=np.select(condlist,choicelist)

    a   b
 0  1   2
 1  2   6
 2  3   12
```

Note: I would go with the suggestions in the comments before embarking on this. The simpler the better.

Answer (score 1):

you want (top answer is better but this is how you would do the if-elif)

```
 if num == 1
    ...
 elif num == 2
    ...
 elif num == 3
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You're multiplying the entire dataframe when you run `df1['b']=df1['a']*2`, instead you need to multiply each element `df1['b'][0]=df1['a'][0]*2`.

So your code will look like this

```
# Start by initialising column 'b'.
df1['b'] = df1['a']

for i in range(len(df1["b"])):
    if df1["a"][i] == 1:
        df1["b"]=df1["a"]*2
    elif df1["a"][i] == 2:
        df1["b"]=df1["a"]*3
    elif df1["a"][i] == 3:
        df1["b"]=df1["a"]*4
```

I'm unsure exactly what you're aiming for, but if you wanted to continue the pattern, your code will look like this is the generic case

```
df1['b'] = df1['a']

for i in range(len(df1["b"])):
    df1["b"][i]=df1["b"][i]*(num+1)
```

Edit: Old answer wasn't a correct solution.